# jdbc driver hang when insert data into TDengine in loop

Tags: java, jdbc, time-series, tdengine

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
TDengine version : 2.2.1.1
taos-driver version : 2.0.34

Bug Description
Using a long connection to execute a loop insert, the program will be stuck for a long time (the duration is uncertain) when the network is disconnected and then resumed. At this point, check the thread information as follows.

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f529c00f000 nid=0x1c28a1 runnable [0x00007f52a0c30000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBJNIConnector.executeQueryImp(Native Method)
at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBJNIConnector.executeQuery(TSDBJNIConnector.java:98)
at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBStatement.executeUpdate(TSDBStatement.java:59)
```

The program prints the execution time as follows, where the second time for disconnection and then recovery

```
1, 2021-11-10T16:51:39.087, insert :1, used:62.248532 ms
2, 2021-11-10T17:08:53.628, insert :1, used:1034040.293917 ms
3, 2021-11-10T17:08:54.209, insert :1, used:81.080271 ms
```

Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Class.forName("com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBDriver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:TAOS://:/data",
"user",
"pass");

    while (true) {
        String sql = " a insert sql";
        try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            int result = statement.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now()
                    + ", insert :" + result + ", used:"
                    + (System.nanoTime()- start)/ 1000000.0 + " ms");
        }
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500L);
    }
}
```

Comment: The "Bug Description" in your question suggests you're trying to file a bug report. Stack Overflow is not the place for that. Bug reports need to be filed with the authors of TDengine. If you want to ask a question, make sure you're actually **asking a question**.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for your suggestion. I used to post my problem to StackOverflow too to expect if someone from here could help me with the solution if it's faster than the response from the author.

Answer (score 0):

From the description, it is saying that it takes a long time to execute the sql of insert for the 2nd time.

The thread information shows that it is executing the native method executeQueryImp, which is probably related to TDengine's Client. You can turn on the logs on the client side and check the execution time of the specific sql statement.